# What are Facebook lists that can be "followed"?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-privacy

On Facebook, under Settings -> Privacy -> Your Activity, there is an option called "Who can see the people, Pages and lists you follow?"

What is a list, and what does it mean to "follow" a list?

Answer (score -1):

**The LIST** is the set of things you follow.
The option gives you the privacy that hides who or the stuff you follow

Comment: What do you mean by "things" and "stuff"? It seems that it's not people nor Pages, because the option says "people, Pages and lists".

Comment: I think it would be the friends list perhaps